# OCaml compile & load during run-time

Tags: ocaml

I am trying to achieve something similar to `eval()` in OCaml.

I have a `string` and I want to get an OCaml function out of it.
Currently I am doing the following:

I dump the string to `new.ml` and compile the file:

```
Compile.implementation Format.std_formatter "new.ml" "New"
```

Then I try to `dynlink` the file:

```
Dynlink.loadfile "new.cmo";
```

But if I try to do `New.foo` it fails. I am not sure why I cannot access the module New after `Dynlink`ing. Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The comment of `Dynlink.loadfile` says:

> No facilities are provided to
>       access value names defined by the unit. Therefore, the unit
>       must register itself its entry points with the main program,
>       e.g. by modifying tables of functions.

The loader program cannot access values of dyn-loaded module without any hint, since it has no idea what values are defined in it just from the `.cmo` file. The dynamic loaded module must register its entry point to some state defined in the loader program.

Here is such a minimal example. First, the module for the entry points:

```
(* entry.ml *)
let f : (unit -> unit) ref = ref (fun () -> assert false)
```

The loader program:

```
(* loader.ml *)
let () =
    Dynlink.loadfile "plugin.cmo";
    !Entry.f ()
```

The plugin to be dyn-loaded:

```
(* plugin.ml *)
let () = Entry.f := (fun () -> prerr_endline "hello world")
```

Here, `Plugin` registers its function to `Entry.f` which is statically linked to `Loader`, so that `Loader` can access the function.

They must be compiled as follows:

```
$ ocamlc -o loader.exe dynlink.cma entry.ml loader.ml
$ ocamlc -c plugin.ml
```

Execution of `loader.exe` should demonstrate how the dyn loading works:

```
$ ./loader.exe
hello world
```

Note that `Entry` and `Loader` must be different modules. Otherwise, you get `Uninitialized_global` exception at dyn-loading `Plugin`. Dyn-loaded modules can only access values in "already initialized modules", and the loader module thinks itself not yet initialized when `Dynlink.loadfile` is called, since the entire evaluation of the module is not finished yet.

`Entry.f` is the simplest state to have only one entry point. To dyn-load many values, you may want to have more complicated data structure, such as `(string, (unit -> unit)) list ref` or `(string, (unit -> unit)) Hashtbl.t`.

Comment: Thanks @camlspotter, for the quick reply. Now I see why I wasn't being able to access the module. But I still have one question - if I do not know the module to be `dynlinked` at compile time (as I mentioned, I am creating it at runtime); how do I access it?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking here, but your program creates new modules therefore the program should know what values are available in plugins. All you need is a proper "protocol" between the loader and plugins, like value `X.x` is registered with a key "X.x" in the entry point hashtbl.