# Ocaml - Runtime compilation of code as a string

Tags: functional-programming, compilation, ocaml, evaluation

I want to parse and compile a function that I have written at runtime, for example I have the following string I generated at runtime:

```ml
let str = "fun x y z -> [x; y; z;]"
```

I am looking for something that will allow me to do something similar to:

```ml
let myfun = eval str 
(* eval returns the value returned by the code in the string so myfun will 
   have the type: 'a -> 'a -> 'a -> 'a list*)
```

Is there a way to do that in OCaml? I came across Dynlink but I am looking for a simpler way to do it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OCaml compile & load during run-time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27398069/ocaml-compile-load-during-run-time)

Comment: No, I was asking for a better solution, but there seems to be no other way to do it.

Comment: No I didn't really think so. The comment is auto-generated when you mark a question as a duplicate, which I did to refer future readers to a more complete answer.

Comment: [Copy-pasting a comment from elsewhere that I thought would be more relevant here:] In OCaml, run-time compilation is relevant in some specific cases, for example for loading plugins from a large application, but it is not a daily programming technique, contrary to some languages with a prominent “eval” feature (most often used to circumvent a limitation of the language).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no easier solution than compiling the code and `Dynlinking` the resulting library.

Or equivalently, one can use the REPL, write the string to the file system and them load it with `#use`.

Depending on your precise use case, MetaOCaml might be an alternative.

Another important point is that types cannot depend on values in a non-dependently typed language. Thus the type of `eval` needs to be restricted. For instance, in the Dynlinking path, the type of dynamically linked functions will be determined by the type of the hooks used to register them.