# Ocaml - writing a function who's number of arguments is determined at runtime

Tags: algorithm, recursion, functional-programming, ocaml

I want to write a function `f`, that takes n arguments, where n is determined at runtime, and might vary at every call to the function, for example

let's say our function `f` takes an integer n which is the number of args, and n args of the same type and turns them into a list:

```ml
# f 3 'a' 'b' 'c';;
- : char list = ['a'; 'b'; 'c']
# f 2 1 2;;
- : int list = [1; 2]
```

I thaught of something like

```ml
let f acc n x =
  if n = 0 
  then List.rev (x::acc)
  else f [x] (x - 1)
```

but in this case it won't work because of the type difference.

Comment: The OCaml type system doesn't really support something like this. Rather than writing the function, it's illuminating just to imagine what type it would have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using currying, you can do something that resembles variadic functions, but you’ll have to convince the type checker. You will not be able to conveniently provide the arity of your function as a bare integer; instead, you can unary-encode the arity as a value of a GADT:

```ml
type (_, 'r) arity =
  | O : ('r, 'r) arity
  | I : ('f, 'r) arity -> (int->'f, 'r) arity
```

The encoding works as follows:

- `O : ('r, 'r) arity` represents the arity of a “function that takes no argument” and returns an `'r`;
- `I O : (int -> 'r, 'r) arity` represents the arity of a function that takes an `int` and then returns an `'r`;
- `I (I O) : (int -> int -> 'r, 'r) arity` represents the arity of a function that takes two `int`s and then returns an `'r`;
- `I (I (I O)) : (int -> int -> int -> 'r, 'r) arity` is the arity of a function that takes three `int`s and then returns an `'r`;
- etc.

Instead of passing `3` as a first argument to your hypothetical variadic function, you would pass `I (I (I O))`. This value describes the sequence of arguments that the function is supposed to take (one int, then one int, then one int, then return). The function would then proceed recursively, destructing (inspecting) this description to decide what to do next You can implement your example function that builds the list of all its arguments, like so:

```ml
let rec f_aux : type f. int list -> (f, int list) arity -> f =
  fun acc arity ->
    begin match arity with
    | O    ->  List.rev acc
    | I a  ->  fun x -> f_aux (x :: acc) a
    end
let f arity = f_aux [] arity
```

```
# f (C(C(C O))) ;;
- : int -> int -> int -> int list = <fun>
# f (C(C(C O))) 111 222 333 ;;
- : int list = [111; 222; 333]
```

As is common with GADTs, type inference is not enough and you have to annotate your definition with the intended type, including an explicit universal quantification (`type f. …` where `f` is the type variable being quantified).

The GADT defined above can only describe variadic functions that deal with `int`s, but notice that you can easily extend it to allow more types of arguments (then of course, you should adapt your variadic functions so that they deal with these added possibilities):

```ml
type (_, 'r) arity =
  | O : ('r, 'r) arity
  | I : ('f, 'r) arity -> (int->'f, 'r) arity
  | B : ('f, 'r) arity -> (bool->'f, 'r) arity
  | C : ('f, 'r) arity -> (char->'f, 'r) arity
  | S : ('f, 'r) arity -> (string->'f, 'r) arity
  (* etc. *)

let rec g_aux : type f. string -> (f, string) arity -> f =
  fun acc arity ->
    begin match arity with
    | O    ->  acc
    | I a  ->  fun x -> g_aux (acc ^ string_of_int x) a
    | B a  ->  fun x -> g_aux (acc ^ if x then "true" else "false") a
    | C a  ->  fun x -> g_aux (acc ^ String.make 1 x) a
    | S a  ->  fun x -> g_aux (acc ^ x) a
    (* etc. *)
    end

let g arity = g_aux "" arity
```

```
# g (S(I(S(B(C O))))) ;;
- : string -> int -> string -> bool -> char -> string = <fun>
# g (S(I(S(B(C O))))) "Number " 42 " is prime. I swear, it’s " true '!' ;;
- : string = "Number 42 is prime. I swear, it’s true!"
```

As a matter of fact, this is essentially how pretty-printing is implemented in OCaml: when you write `Printf.printf "%s%b" …`, the format string is not actually a `string`, it is syntactic sugar kindly supplied by the compiler for a value of some very complicated GADT type such as `(_,_,_,_,_,_) format6` (6 type parameters!). You might just as well build the GADT value by hand (don’t). This syntactic sugar is the only magic that the compiler does for pretty-printing, everything else works with standard language features.

Well, we have a system that works, at least it typechecks. Syntax is not pretty unless the compiler gives you sugar. More importantly, arities are encoded and checked within the *static* type system, which means, they are known at compile-time. You cannot (or at least it’s hard to do safely) read an arity as input of your program, dynamically, at run-time.

The actual question is: why would you actually *need* to do that, instead of just using a list? It brings nothing except syntactic convenience perhaps.

Comment: That's very interesting. In my case I don't have the option of using lists, as I'm using a function from a library which returns values not as a list, I was looking for the function to turn those values into a list for that reason. Do you have any papers, books, or other sources on coding with GADTs and using them as an intermediary to functions? I am not familiar with that technique.

Comment: Is it an OCaml function you are calling? What type of data structure does it return? Why not use this data structure directly? Anyway, if you want to write a function that would turn it into a list, this function would take the whole data structure as a single argument.
It seems you are confusing program code with program data. As Jeffrey Schofield said in the other answer, there is no hope for consuming data like that, unless you are willing to generate and compile OCaml code on-the-fly (as I see you are trying to do [in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66986278)).

Comment: On GADTs: Generalized Algebraic DataTypes are an advanced feature of OCaml. Briefly, they are a tool for statically imposing a finer discipline in your code, by pushing the type system to its limits. They are described [in the manual](https://ocaml.org/manual/gadts.html) with several common examples, however perhaps the reading is not fit for a beginner. You can find various explanations on the web, for instance [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/ocaml/comments/1jmjwf/) or [there](https://engineering.issuu.com/2015/09/17/gadt-practicalities) (these 2 links are just examples of what you can find).

Comment: Yes it's an OCaml function, I'm using the Crowbar library to generate values, so there is a map function that takes n generators as a list, and returns n values generated by those generators, and expected to get a function that takes those n arguments and composes them into some data structure. So in my case the function doesn't return a data structure but free values that I want to put into  a data structure (a list)

Comment: At first I thought your solution would work, but now That I'm looking at it more closely I notice, that it still requires that the arity struct be built before the function gets called, which is not possible to do. What I mean is, given the number of arguments, there noway of building the adequate struct for the function, it's impossible to create a function ```g``` in a way that ```g 3 = I (I (I O))``` and ```g 2 = I (I O)``` because of the type difference between the structs

Comment: I see! In [the interface of Crowbar](https://github.com/stedolan/crowbar/blob/master/src/crowbar.mli), notice that `map` does not take a usual list (despite the convenient syntax), rather it takes a value of type `(_, _) gens`, which is a GADT similar to my arity GADT. :-) For instance, in this context, `[ bool ; int ; char ]` is of type `(bool->int->char->'r, 'r) gens`. The builder function does not need to be of variable arity, because the “list” given to `map` cannot be an arbitrary list: its type (hence length) is fixed at compile-time, so the type of your builder function is known too.

Comment: Ok, so I wouldn't even be able to have undetermined length lists as arguments to the map function in the first place. This is pretty limiting, but I guess it's the downside of strongly-typed safe languages, Thanks for the answers :)

Comment: If you want to generate list values, Crowbar has a list generator: `list : 'a gen -> 'a list gen`.

Comment: true, but in my case I wanted to use a list of generators that return values of the same type, but not necessarily of the structure, something like ```Crowbar.map mylist (fun x1 x2 ... xn -> [x1; x2; ... xn])``` That way by using another ```Crowbar.map``` I would be able to recover the list and do things with it, but well that's not possible, thanks for the answers and discussion :)

Answer (score 2):

Your requirement  doesn't make sense, since there is no way to dynamically change the number of parameters of a function at runtime. The number of parameters in any function call is directly visible by examining the text of the source code:

```
f a b    (* Two parameters *)
f a b c  (* Three parameters *)
```

There is no dynamic evaluation mechanism in OCaml (like the `eval` mechanism of other languages). This is part of what it means to be statically typed.

You can get the effect you want just by passing a list to the function.

Comment: What I was hoping for was something similar to a fold_left that doesn't expect a list as an argument, but a sort of flow of values in which we know the total number of values.

Comment: In OCaml you can (just barely) write functions that take different numbers of parameters at each call. That's quite different from a number that varies dynamically at runtime. One example is `Printf.printf`. But even this requires some compiler magic. I don't see any true advantage to writing `f a b c` and `f a b`  instead of `f [a; b; c]` and `f [a; b]`. But as a puzzle it's interesting.

Comment: Printf doesn't require any compiler magic (except for the syntax), only GADTs.

Comment: Well in my case it's not a really a choice. I'm pretty sure it's not possible, but out of curiosity I want to ask, is there a way to go from ```a b c``` to ```[a; b; c]```? Of course when a, b and c are values of the same type, that are not caught by variables.

Comment: I consider the results of `format_of_string "%d"` to be fairly magical. I don't see how to write such a function myself. But it could just be my own ignorance.

Comment: @JeffreyScofield `format_of_string` is of type `_ format6 -> _ format6` (omitting all type parameters for brevity). It’s most likely the identity function. The magic is only in that wherever a format6 is expected, the compiler accepts a string syntax as sugar, which it unfolds into a format6 value. So `format_of_string "%i"` and `let s : _ format6 = "%i" in format_of_string s` both work, but `let s = "%i" in format_of_string s` doesn’t.